# Filter ListView using EditText

Tags: java, android

Basically I'm trying to filter a ListView using an EditText. I manage to store all the filtered results but seems like I'm missing something since the UI is not updated and it's not displaying anything on text changed. Any indications? Thanks

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.enloop.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FriendsWithMeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<FriendsModel> friend;
    private ArrayList<FriendsModel> items = new ArrayList<FriendsModel>();
    private ArrayList<FriendsModel> suggestions = new ArrayList<FriendsModel>();

    public FriendsWithMeAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<FriendsModel> ai) {
        mContext = c;
        friend = ai;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return friend.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return friend.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_friend, null);
        }
        ImageView userImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invited_friend_picture);
        ImageView checkImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invite_friends_check);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invited_friend_name);
        TextView userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invited_friend_name);

        userImage.setImageBitmap(friend.get(position).getUserImage());
        checkImage.setImageResource(friend.get(position).isWithMe() ?
                R.drawable.btn_checkmark_round_tiny : R.drawable.btn_before_checkmark_round_tiny);

        String userEnloopNameString = friend.get(position).getName();
        name.setText(userNameString);


        String userNameString = friend.get(position).getUserName();
        if (userNameString.length() > 12) {
            userNameString = userNameString.substring(0, 10);
            userNameString += "..";
        }
        userName.setText(userNameString);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint == null && constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.values = friend;
                    results.count = friend.size();
                } else {
                    for (FriendsModel item : friend) {
                        if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                            suggestions.add(item);
                    }
                    results.values = suggestions;
                    results.count = suggestions.size();
                }

                return results;
            }


            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                if (results.count == 0) {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                } else {
                    items = (ArrayList<FriendsModel>) results.values;
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}




mSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: you are missing adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() i guess inside onTextChanged

Comment: @IllegalArgument still not displaying anything

Comment: Add more details please

Comment: `items` field is not used

Comment: `it's not displaying anything on text changed.`. Don't believe you. It just will display the same as before as `friend` is not changed at all.

Comment: @greenapps it is not display anything at all
 - pskink yes, indeed. I should be using that array to output the filtered items for the ListView

Comment: Akex,  honestly,  use SimpleCursorAdapter + FilterQueryProvider as i told you yesterday, now you concentrate on data structures,  on adding items on changing references,  with FQP you are dealing with data,  not data structures, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara

Comment: `it is not display anything at all`. What does this have to do with filtering if it does niot display anything to begin with?

Comment: @greenapps managed to display everything, list is being filtered by the EditText but problem is when I delete the text, it doesn't come back to the state where the list is fully populated with all the friends, but it shows me the filtered one

Comment: As you can see on an answer you have to refill friend with the original content if a backspace is involved. And certainlt when results.count==0.

Comment: @greenapps just made of copy of the initial array and restoring than when backspacing :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
mSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           adapter.filter(text);
      }
});
```

Here use two list one for original data and another one for filtered data please keep mind you can not use (=)assignment for filtered data if you do this way then you filtered data also alter original data too,filtered data use to shown list list item so you have to use addAll() instead (=) assignment which is not altered original data and whenever you use custom adapter try to use [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern.

```
public class FriendsWithMeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<FriendsModel> friend;
    private ArrayList<FriendsModel> suggestions = new ArrayList<FriendsModel>();

    public FriendsWithMeAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<FriendsModel> friend) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.friend = friend;
        suggestions =new ArrayList<FriendsModel>();
        suggestions.addAll(friend);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return suggestions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return suggestions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView =  LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_friend, null);
            holder.userImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invited_friend_picture);
            holder.checkImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invite_friends_check);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invited_friend_name);
            holder.userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invited_friend_name);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.userImage.setImageBitmap(suggestions.get(position).getUserImage());
        holder.checkImage.setImageResource(suggestions.get(position).isWithMe() ?
                R.drawable.btn_checkmark_round_tiny : R.drawable.btn_before_checkmark_round_tiny);

        String userEnloopNameString = suggestions.get(position).getName();
        holder.name.setText(userNameString);


        String userNameString = suggestions.get(position).getUserName();
        if (userNameString.length() > 12) {
            userNameString = userNameString.substring(0, 10);
            userNameString += "..";
        }
        holder.userName.setText(userNameString);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        suggestions.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            suggestions.addAll(friend);
        }else{
            for (FriendsModel item : friend) {
                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                    suggestions.add(item);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView userImage;
        ImageView checkImage;
        TextView name;
        TextView userName;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but it's still not doing the trick :(