# Using an EditText to search through a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I'm trying to search through a ListView With the use of a TextView, after writing the code, it was Logging out what I did, but not filtering the List I want it to filter. Here is my code:

```
public class LabDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private LabAdapter labListAdapter;
    private List<LabItem> labItem;
    private TextView searchText;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.assigned_lab_fragments);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Labs");

        searchText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labText);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        labItem = new ArrayList<LabItem>();
        labListAdapter = new LabAdapter(this, labItem);
        list.setAdapter(labListAdapter);
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new ListItemClickListener());
        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            /*labListAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
            list.setAdapter(labListAdapter);*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            int textLength = charSequence.length();
            List<LabItem> labItemss = new ArrayList<LabItem>();
            for (LabItem ll : labItem){
                if(textLength <= ll.getName().length()){
                    if (ll.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        labItemss.add(ll);
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d("SIZE OF SEARCH", String.valueOf(labItemss.size()));
            labListAdapter = new LabAdapter(LabDetailActivity.this, labItemss);
            list.setAdapter(labListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            /*Log.d("NEW TAGS", "*** Search value changed: " + editable.toString());
            if (editable.toString().length() >= 3)
                labListAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable.toString());*/
            //labListAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable.toString());
            //labListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    }

    private class ListItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    }

    private void RetrieveData(){
        Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("content://" + getString(R.string.LEONE_AUTHORITY) + "/olabs");
        Log.d("URL PRINT", uri2.toString());
        final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri2, null, null, null, "_id");
        Log.d("CURSOR DATA:", cursor.toString());
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    object.put("lab_number", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lab_case_number")));
                    object.put("lab_name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lab_case_name")));
                    array.put(object);
                    Log.d("ARRAY", String.valueOf(array.length()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            parseJsonLabs(array);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    private void parseJsonLabs(JSONArray array){

        Log.d("CASESARRAY", array.toString());
        try {
            labItem.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject cases = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                LabItem items = new LabItem();

                items.setName(cases.getString("lab_number"));
                items.setCase(cases.getString("lab_name"));
                labItem.add(items);
            }
            labListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("ARRAYTEST", "ERROR:", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        RetrieveData();
    }
}
```

Then, the Adapter code is here
**Adapter**

```
public class LabAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<LabItem> labItem;
    private TextView labName, labCase;

    public LabAdapter(Activity activity, List<LabItem> labItem){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.labItem = labItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return labItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return labItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_lab_activity_list, null);

        labName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_lab_name);
        labCase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_lab_case);

        LabItem labs = labItem.get(position);
        labName.setText(labs.getName());
        labCase.setText(labs.getCase());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                Log.d("SEARCHTEXT2", "**** PERFORM FILTERING for: " + charSequence);
                charSequence = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                FilterResults filts = new FilterResults();
                if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
                    filts.values = labItem;
                    filts.count = labItem.size();
                } else {
                    // We perform filtering operation
                    List<LabItem> labrs = new ArrayList<LabItem>();
                    for (LabItem l : labrs){
                        if (l.getName().startsWith(charSequence.toString()) || l.getCase().startsWith(charSequence.toString()))
                            labItem.add(l);
                    }
                    filts.values = labItem;
                    filts.count = labItem.size();
                    //filts.count = labItem.size();
                }
                return filts;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
                Log.d("SEARCHTEXT1", "**** PUBLISHING RESULTS for: " + charSequence);
                if (filterResults.count == 0)
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                else {
                    labItem = (List<LabItem>) filterResults.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged(){
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And the Item class is here
**Item Class**

```
public class LabItem {

    String labCase, labName;

    public LabItem() {

    }

    public LabItem(String labCase, String labName){
        super();
        this.labCase = labCase;
        this.labName = labName;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return labName;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.labName = name;
    }

    public String getCase(){
        return labCase;
    }

    public void setCase(String cases){
        this.labCase = cases;
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm not updating the ListView very well or something. When I type a i see the count, but If I add another letter. The **LIST** would be gone. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652707/filter-listview-using-edittext/26653091#26653091

Comment: try invalidating the adapter before setting or notifyDataSetChanged() thereby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few Logical Mistakes : I got here this code working at my end**

```
    public LabAdapter(Activity activity, List<LabItem> labItem){
        this.activity = activity;

        this.labItem = labItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return labItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public LabItem getItem(int position) { //instead of Object make it Labitem
        return labItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_stack, null);

        labName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        labCase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        LabItem labs = labItem.get(position);
        labName.setText(labs.getName());
        labCase.setText(labs.getCase());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                Log.d("SEARCHTEXT2", "**** PERFORM FILTERING for: " + charSequence);
                charSequence = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                FilterResults filts = new FilterResults();
                if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
                    filts.values = labItem;
                    filts.count = labItem.size();
                } else {
                    // We perform filtering operation
                    List<LabItem> labrs = new ArrayList<LabItem>();
                    for (LabItem l : labItem){ //you are going to search in labItem that contains the data and not the empty list labrs
                        if (l.getName().startsWith(charSequence.toString()) || l.getCase().startsWith(charSequence.toString())){
                               Log.e("(l.getName().startsWith(charSequence.toString())","" + charSequence);
                               labrs.add(l); // add to the new list** 
                        }
                    }
                    filts.values = labrs; //set values to the new list**
                    filts.count = labrs.size(); 
                    //filts.count = labItem.size();
                }
                return filts;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
                Log.d("SEARCHTEXT1", "**** PUBLISHING RESULTS for: " + charSequence);
                List<LabItem> filtered = (List<LabItem>) filterResults.values;

                labItem = filtered; // set the new data as you want  with the new set you've received.**
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        };
    }

public void notifyDataSetInvalidated()
{
    super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
```

---

then in your **LabDetailActivity.class** change it as

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                labListAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
                Log.d("NEW TAGS", "*** Search value changed: " + labListAdapter.getCount());
                list.invalidate();
                labListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setAdapter(labListAdapter);

            }
```

**Edit:**

> P.S. This code is still not perfect as after clearing the text it
>   doesn't sets the list back. I leave it to you. Hope this solves your
>   problem you've been facing.
>   Let me know if it works.

Comment: great to know. One more thing move the filter code to onTextChanged instead of beforeTextChanged and use interface for passing data to adapter and activity for proper functionality of search. this is the answer for my note. :)